# Is $f - 3I$ an isomorphism if $f$ is orthogonal?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, orthogonality, vector-space-isomorphism

> Decide if the following statement is true or false by briefly
>   justify the answer.
>
> Let $(V, \phi)$ be a real Euclidean space of dimension $n$, and let
>   $f: V \to V$ be an orthogonal operator. Then the operator $f-3I$ is an
>   isomorphism (where $I$ = identity).

Could you give me any hint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that $f - 3I$ is no isomorphism. Then the equation $fv = 3v$ has a non-trivial solution $v \neq 0$. This is equivalent to the fact that $f$ has eigenvalue $3$. But since $f$ is orthogonal, all eigenvalues of $f$ lie on the unit circle, i.e., they have absolute value $1$. Thus, $3$ can't be an eigenvalue of $f$.

---

The idea of the proof that all eigenvalues $\lambda$ of $f$ orthogonal fulfill $\lvert \lambda \rvert = 1$ is discussed e.g. in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3169070/eigenvalues-of-a-real-orthogonal-matrix?rq=1) question.

Comment: I don't know. Please, could you finish your reasoning? Is it about all the eigenvalues can only be 1 or -1?

Comment: @conradDell I wrote a complete answer. Note that the eigenvalues in general are complex and have absolute value $1$. They are $\pm 1$ in case of they are real.